# dynamic height content max height 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `wrapper` with

```
position: fixed;
```

and `sub-wrapper` with

```
max-height: 100%;
```

(its height needs to be dynamic, so I cannot set height: 100%)

and inside of that `sub-wrapper` is `header` with static height, and `content` with dynamic height.

Is there pure CSS way to make `content`'s `max-height` to be equal 100% - 50px? To not overflow `sub-wrapper`.

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  background: #dadada;
}
.sub-wrapper {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  max-height: 100%;
}
header {
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.content {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sub-wrapper">
    <header>header</header>
    <div class="content">
      lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas ullam quaerat dignissimos quasi, rerum architecto amet ratione nostrum rem ipsa accusantium, esse aliquam assumenda tempore, porro cum? Non, a, maxime.
      <br>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas ullam quaerat dignissimos quasi, rerum architecto amet ratione nostrum rem ipsa accusantium, esse aliquam assumenda tempore, porro cum? Non, a, maxime.
      <br>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas ullam quaerat dignissimos quasi, rerum architecto amet ratione nostrum rem ipsa accusantium, esse aliquam assumenda tempore, porro cum? Non, a, maxime.
      <br>met ratione nostrum rem ipsa accusantium, esse aliquam assumenda tempore, porro cum? Non, a, maxime.
      <br>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas ullam quaerat dignissimos quasi, rerum architecto amet ratione nostrum rem ipsa accusantium, esse aliquam assumenda tempore, porro cum? Non, a, maxime.
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And here is working example in chrome https://jsfiddle.net/5rqcpcf4/, but I need it also for IE 11.

Comment: why don't you use max-height: calc(100% - 50px) in your content?

Comment: don't you want something like https://jsfiddle.net/5rqcpcf4/3/ ?

Comment: content exceedes subwrapper

Comment: when you say that it exceedes the subwrapper, does it mean that you want it to be scrollable ?

Comment: @QoP, yes I want it to be scrollable also. and if its height was 100% - 50px - `overflow: auto;` would work, but it isnt.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/5rqcpcf4/2/

Just position header absolutely if it has fixed height.

```
       .wrapper{
            padding: 10px;
            position: fixed;
            left: 10px;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 50px;
            background: #dadada;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .sub-wrapper{
            background: white;
            padding: 10px;
            max-height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        header{
            height: 50px;
            background: lightblue;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
        .content{
            background: gold;
        }
```

Comment: hacky a little, but fallback option

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [CSS display table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display?)

```
display: table;
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ht3bvvyx/

It works on IE 8+

Comment: but content isnt scrolling

Comment: @АртемСвирский you'll need to add overflow: scroll for that.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oakley808/trLathcv/2/

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use css calc method:

```
max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
```

Comment: Don't forget to apply max-height: 100% and overflow: auto; with .content selector